# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when I make a string of characters

Tags: java

Ok so I'm trying to generate a random character generator that goes beyond simple numbers and letters. I want to simultaneously create a replica of that same generator for the purpose of comparing them and having it print out how many attempts it took for "Cracker" to match the value of "Generator" because I'm interested in the concept after reading a bit of cryptography. When parsing the characters to a string, I get an OutOfBoundsException, but why? I can't seem to find much on the limitations of string. I would think it would have to been an issue besides the string not being able to take the characters but I can't figure it out.

```
 import java.util.Random;
public class Class {

public static void Generator(){
      Random r = new Random();      
      String[] cArray = new String[10];     
      for(int i = 0; i <= cArray.length; i++){
          char c = (char)(r.nextInt(200) + 'a');
          String y = Character.toString(c);
            cArray[i] = y;
            System.out.print(cArray[i]);
              }       
      }


public static void Cracker(){
      Random s = new Random();

      String[] bArray = new String[10];
      for(int x = 0; x <= bArray.length; x++){
          char b = (char)(s.nextInt(100) + 'a');
            String z = Character.toString(b);
            bArray[x] = z;
            System.out.print(bArray[x]);
              } 
      }





public static void main(String[] args) {


          Generator();




}

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You get a stack trace that tells you exactly where this occurs.  You get an exception message that tells you how big the array is and what index was used.  You've chosen to not show us either.  Have you looked at them yourself??

Comment: It was telling me it was happening at cArray[i] = y; But I wasn't sure what exactly it was telling me. Thats all the information I unintentionally omitted. It said 10
 at Class.Generator(Class.java:10)
 at Class.main(Class.java:34)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= cArray.length; i++)
                  ^^^^
```

Change to

```
for (int i = 0; i < cArray.length; i++)
                 ^^^^
```

In both your `for` loops.

An array of length n has elements from `0` to `n-1` - i.e. array `arr` of length 3 has elements `arr[0]`, `arr[1]` & `arr[2]`.

Comment: WHY DIDN'T I CONSIDER THE ARRAY. Oh man, That went WAY over my head. Thank you!! I'm glad it was something simple.